# What is the limit of $(1-\frac1n)$ in this topology?

Tags: general-topology

On $E=[0,1[$ I consider the topology $$\tau=\{[0,x[, x\in [0,1]\}$$

How to find the limit of $u_n=1-\frac1n$?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for any open set $[0,x[$, $0 < x < 1$: as $(1 - 1/n) > x$ for $n$ large enough, $(1 - 1/n)\not\in [0,x[$ for $n$ large enough...

Comment: how to prove that an infinite number is not in the open set ?

Comment: @PolineSandra, $(1−1/n)>x\iff n > 1/(1-x)$.

Comment: for example why 0 is not a limit ? $u_n\in [0,\varepsilon[ \iff n<1-\varepsilon$ how to find the counter example such that 0 is not a limit

Comment: @Poline: We can't have $0$ as a limit point, because $u_1=0$ is the only sequence element in $\left[0,\frac12\right[.$

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, you can't, because it doesn't exist.

Take any $x\in E.$ By definition of $E,$ we know that $0\le x<1,$ and so by definition of $\tau,$ the open neighborhoods of $x$ will be of the form $[0,y[$ for some $y\in]x,1].$ However, taking $y=\frac{x+1}2,$ we see that only finitely-many $u_n$ will be in the set $[0,y[,$ so $u_n$ can't converge to $x.$

On the other hand, if we'd had the set $E=[0,1]$ and had $\tau=\bigl\{[0,x[\::x\in[0,1]\bigr\}\cup\{E\},$ then we would find that $1$ is the limit of $u_n.$

Or, with the original $E$ and $\tau,$ if we'd considered $v_n=\frac1{n+1},$ we would find that $v_n$ converges to ***every point of $E$!***

---

Let me see if I can expand on my approach above.

First of all, note that for any $x\in E$ and any $\varepsilon,$ the following are equivalent: $$x\in[0,x+\varepsilon[\;\text{ and }\;[0,x+\varepsilon[\,\in\tau\\x<x+\varepsilon\le 1\\0<\varepsilon\le 1-x\\\varepsilon\in\,]0,1-x]$$

Next, note that for any $n\in\Bbb N,$ any $x\in E,$ and any $\varepsilon\in\,]0,1-x],$ the following are equivalent: $$u_n\in[0,x+\varepsilon[\\0\le1-\frac1n<x+\varepsilon\\\frac1n\le 1<\frac1n+x+\varepsilon\\1\le n<1+(x+\varepsilon)n\\n<1+(x+\varepsilon)n\\n-(x+\varepsilon)n<1\\n\bigl(1-(x+\varepsilon)\bigr)<1\\n<\frac{1}{1-(x+\varepsilon)}\\1\le n<\frac{1}{1-(x+\varepsilon)}\\1\le n<\left\lceil\frac{1}{1-(x+\varepsilon)}\right\rceil\\1\le n\le\left\lceil\frac{1}{1-(x+\varepsilon)}\right\rceil-1$$

Hence, we have in particular that there are only $\left\lceil\frac{1}{1-(x+\varepsilon)}\right\rceil-1$ values of $n$ for which $u_n\in[0,x+\varepsilon[.$ Since all neighborhoods of $x$ have the form $[0,x+\varepsilon[$ for some $\varepsilon\in\,]0,1-x],$ then regardless of $x,$ every neighborhood of $x$ has only finitely-many $u_n$ inside it.

Comment: I don't understand, in class we work with $\varepsilon$: If I say let $l\in E$ the open neighborhood is $[0,l+\varepsilon[,\varepsilon>0$, when $n>\frac{1}{1-(l+\varepsilon)}$ the sequence is in $[0,l+\varepsilon[$ how to prove that there is only a finit number? @Cameron Buie

Comment: sorry, $n<\frac{1}{1-(l-\varepsilon)}$ with $l-\varepsilon\leq 1$ how to say that it is a finite number?

Comment: Nice catch! Note that for $0<\varepsilon<1-l,$ we will have that $\frac{1}{1-(l+\varepsilon)}$ is a positive real number. But given any positive real number $x,$ there cannot be infinitely-many natural numbers less than $x.$ If there were, then $x$ would be greater than ***all*** of the natural numbers, but there isn't any real number greater than all of the natural numbers. Thus, there are only finitely-many $n$ less than $\frac{1}{1-(l+\varepsilon)}.$

Comment: I don't understand what you write

Comment: Well, what are some facts you know about the natural numbers? If you can give me something to go on, I may be able to clarify what I've written.

Comment: to say that the sequence do not converge it means that $\exists \varepsilon, \forall n_0\in \mathbb{N}, \exists n\in \mathbb{N}; n\geq n_0 ~\text{and}~ u_n\geq l-\varepsilon$ what we choose $\varepsilon$ ?

Comment: I have no idea where "$\exists \varepsilon, \forall n_0\in \mathbb{N}, \exists n\in \mathbb{N}; n\geq n_0 ~\text{and}~ u_n\geq l-\varepsilon$" came from. It seems you probably were negating a definition of sequence convergence, but that's nothing close to the definition I'd expect, so I don't know what else I can do to help you, at present. Please include your thoughts, relevant definitions, and efforts in your question, so that someone may be able to help you.

Comment: i read again you answer and I understand thank you the natural numbers have not an upper bound

Comment: @Poline: Precisely! Well done. :-)

Comment: I am currently in the process of expanding on my answer. It's good to know that you've determined the key point!

Comment: @downvoter: Care to offer some constructive criticism?